# Numbering figures and tables in a problem set

Tags: floats, numbering, enumerate, chngcntr

A standard problem set from a physics textbook is divided into sections, with problems numbered sequentially from start to finish (i.e., not resetting in every section). Tables and figures are numbered as the problems, without any extra sub-numbering, because it is assumed that no problem will be associated with more than one table or figure (and if that were the case, it would probably get an a,b,c,... sub-numbering, only when needed). This means that problem 8 goes with figure 8 and problem 15 with figure 15, even if all problems in between lack any figures.

I've used the `enumerate` package to achieve sequential numbering of the problems, and it works beautifully, but so far I have not succeeded in getting tables and figures numbered in the same way as the problems. The `chngcntr` package comes close to providing the functionality I need, but, as far as I can see, it always assumes that a sub-numbering scheme should take place, so that I get figure 5.1 accompanying problem 5, which is not what I want (because there is no figure 5.2).

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `\renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{problem}}` should probably work

Comment: Worked perfectly. As I haven't defined a specific counter for the problems, I needed to use `\renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{enumi}}`. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to make `figure` use the same counter but actually it's simpler just to let it carry on using a `figure` counter and just print the current counter from problems.

If you are using the `enumi` counter for problems:

```
\renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{enumi}}
```